# Flask Framework question - how to display correct answers in quiz

Tags: python, flask

I am just learning how to use Flask:

I have this code for a simple guessing game(quiz), and in the review html where the user see their answer versus the correct one, their answer(written 'as your answer' is not showing, but only the correct answer.

Here is my app.py file the with routes. The route with the issue is the one that says @app.route('/answer', methods=['POST']).  Kindy assist if you can!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define the trivia questions and answers
questions = [
    {
        'question': 'What is the capital of France?',
        'options': ['Berlin', 'Madrid', 'Paris', 'Rome'],
        'correct_answer': 'Paris',
        'message': '',
    },
    {
        'question': 'Which planet is known as the Red Planet?',
        'options': ['Mars', 'Venus', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn'],
        'correct_answer': 'Mars',
        'message': '',
    },
    {
        'question': 'What is the largest mammal in the world?',
        'options': ['Elephant', 'Giraffe', 'Whale Shark', 'Kangaroo'],
        'correct_answer': 'Whale Shark',
        'message': '',
    },
]

# Initialize variables to keep track of the current question and the user's score
current_question = 0
score = 0

def reset_messages():
    for question in questions:
        question['message'] = ''

@app.route('/')
def index():
    reset_messages()
    if current_question < len(questions):
        return render_template('question.html', question=questions[current_question])
    else:
        return render_template('result.html', score=score, total=len(questions), questions=questions)

@app.route('/answer', methods=['POST'])
def answer():
    global current_question, score

    user_answer = request.form.get('answer')
    correct_answer = questions[current_question]['correct_answer']

    if user_answer == correct_answer:
        score += 1
    else:
        questions[current_question]['message'] = user_answer  # Set user's answer here

    current_question += 1

    if current_question < len(questions):
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        # Ensure the score does not exceed the total number of questions
        score = min(score, len(questions))
        # Reset the current_question to 0 for review
        current_question = 0
        return redirect(url_for('review', score=score, total=len(questions)))

@app.route('/play-again', methods=['POST'])
def play_again():
    global current_question, score
    current_question = 0
    score = 0
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/review')
def review():
    return render_template('review.html', questions=questions, score=score, total=len(questions))

@app.route('/quit', methods=['POST'])
def quit_game():
    return 'Thank you for playing!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

below is the review, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Review Answers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Review Answers</h1>
    <p>Your score: {{ score }} out of {{ total }}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for question in questions %}
        <li>
            {{ question['question'] }}<br>
            {% if question['message'] == 'Correct!' %}
                Correct answer: {{ question['correct_answer'] }} (Correct)
            {% else %}
                Your answer: {{ question['message'] }}<br>
                Correct answer: {{ question['correct_answer'] }}
            {% endif %}<br>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="/">Back to Main Page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just to add, alternatively, I am trying to find a way to let the user know their correct answers as they progress through the questions or something like that.

Comment: You can [edit] the post if you have more information to add. You might want to include all of your templates so the example is complete and reproducible. That said, why use globals rather than session state? Every user will be working on the same quiz otherwise.